# Magento Billing Adress name being created wrongly with onboarding customers

Tags: magento, paypal

[Magento Order Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkaRZ.jpg)

The magento orders placed with PayPal and with new customers are being created with concatenated data, as you can see on the screenshot.

The billing address name is being generated with the full checkout customer name plus the full paypal customer name.

Anyone have an idea why this happening?